# There are times when I can't see comments I have posted

Tags: support

Why do my comments sometimes seem to disappear or become invisible to me? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell us some posts where this seems to have happened to you?

Comment: While we wait for a more authoritative answer my suggestion is that it can be due to general house cleaning by our moderators. If this is the case you would also see that other comments disappear at the same time.

Comment: The missing comment is now (22:00 EST) visible [see](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220368/an-adjective-for-someone-who-doesnt-really-care). Though I can't recall dates/times now, this has occurred a half-dozen times. Have you ever run into this before?

Comment: I have noticed that due to browser caching behavior sometimes a comment is not visible until a true page refresh is performed.

Comment: That might be it, @Jim. Thanks.

Comment: @LittleEva - the only time this happens that I've noticed is when you go *back* to a page. You will not see your comments or your votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use your "back" button to go back to a page, it will be to the version you first opened, without any of your votes, comments, or edits. You need to do a refresh to see the content you added. (Or, navigate back to the page using links rather than your "back" button, but that's not always possible.)

If the comment doesn't appear even after a refresh, it may have been deleted. If a comment is added automatically on your behalf as a result of a close vote, it's subject to automatic deletion if and when the closure actually takes place. This is true even if you edited the automatic comment. And of course moderators can delete comments.

Comment: Thank Ya'll - all these responses have been helpful and are greatly appreciated. As is usually the case, I am my own obstacle. :-)

Comment: To add to this answer, everything which happens while the page is open (like comments appearing -- including your own -- and votes and inbox and such updating) is done without involving the browser history. They are all dynamic updates to the page, with websockets and AJAX if you're into that level of detail. So when you ask the browser to go back to the page, it opens what it opened before, without all the updates. When you *refresh* the page, all those updates are delivered from the server as part of the page, and "baked in". But then any updates which happen after that won't be, and so on.